# If there is same content on knowledge base article and website page then it Google considered it duplicate?

Tags: google

We are having a knowledge base on freshdesk (support articles) and some website pages have the same content as on knowledge base article. I want to know does Google consider this as duplicate content. Do I need to delete or redirect the page to the knowledgebase article?

This is a website page
https://www.casefox.com/web/lawpay.html

and this is a knowledge base article
http://support.casefox.com/support/solutions/articles/17000022820-accepting-invoice-and-trust-payments-via-lawpay

Answer (score 1):

### Do nothing.

What you're doing is natural, and Google understands why you're doing it.

Ultimately, they will serve the page that is most relevant to the searcher.

The keywords in the query, a user's search history, or any other relevant data available on a user's local network can help search engines decide what *relevant* means.

The outcome of gathering this data is this data is understanding a user's intent. Understanding this helps ensure high likelihood that the page shown to a user matches the reason they're searching for it.

Like I always say...Google ranks pages, not sites!

Just because 2 pages have sections with pieces of the same content does not mean that the pages are *duplicative*.

You could have a same block of text on the page about your window treatment product or your guide to treating windows.

To me, the word "duplicate content" is a deceiving.

At least within the realm of Google Search.

You'll know when you're doing something wrong when it doesn't feel right :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is absolutely duplicate content. When Google encounters two pages with the same content, it will choose to index one of them and ignore the other one. Google won't penalize your site for doing this. Google only penalizes sites for having duplicate content when it is spammy or copied from other sites. See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

The only reason to redirect one page to the other would be if you had a preference for which one Google indexes.  For example the page on your main site is prettier, so you might prefer that Google index that one, so you could redirect your knowledge base article to it.

Instead of redirects, you could choose to use [canonical link tags](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls#rel-canonical-link-method) to tell Google which is the preferred page. That way you could have both pages on your site, but still have Google index the one you choose.

A third option would be to use a [noindex meta tag](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/block-indexing) on one of the pages to tell Google that you prefer that that page not be indexed. I'd prefer to use redirects or canonical tags over noindex if possible though because the other solutions tell Google about the relationship.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But freshdesk does not provide a canonical link tag and noindex meta tag feature on knowledge base articles

Comment: The you are limited to which one you can set as the canonical, but letting Google figure it out on its own can work.  If you link more to the main site, Google is likely to choose that one as the canonical.

Comment: ok, thank you Stephen